# Will multipart upload with S3 overcome the Lambda 6MB request payload limit?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm making a lambda function that will generate a pdf file that then needs to be sent to S3.

The file is generated in the lambda function, so I can't use a pre-signed url to upload it from the client since the client does not have the file. The file generated will not be on the range of 512MB (lambda /tmp storage limit) but will be more than 6MB.

I'm not sure yet if i should convert this to a container instead since lambda has a maximum request payload of 6MB.

One idea that came to mind is to use s3 multipart-upload and upload the parts into chunks of 4MB.

Does that actually solve the problem though? Or should i just create a container instead?

Taking into account lambda cost savings having a way to go around the lambda 6MB limit would be very beneficial in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6 MB limit is for data you **send back to** or **receive from your users** in synchronous calls. You can upload the results to S3 and send the caller a presigned-URL to the object, that is a common pattern and brings you nowhere near the 6 MB limit.

Src: [Lambda limits documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

Comment: So that means i can send a put request to S3 for a file that is over 6MB and that limit is not applicable in this case?

Comment: Exactly, you're only limited by the timeout of your function and the network throughput available to it, which scales based on the memory that you assigned to the function. (The throughput doesn't limit the size of the data, but how fast you can send it and in combination with the timeout that effectively limits the size).

Comment: @AurelDrejta Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you, that shows other users this question has been resolved :-)